# AJAX function does not return any value

Tags: javascript, ajax, return-value

### Problem

I have a JavaScript function which uses AJAX for getting a value from a MySQL table through PHP. I wrote all of my PHP and AJAX code correctly because when I check the result it receives, it shows the value as I want it to. So, the problem is when I receive the data correctly, I try to return it. But when I tried calling that function, even though it shows the correct value when I try seeing the value inside the AJAX function, as soon as I return it and check where I call the function, it shows "undefined".

### Code Used

This is the AJAX function code -

```
function CheckUser(EmailID) {
     alert(EmailID);
     $.ajax("AJAXcommands\\CheckUser.php", {
          type: "POST", // type of the data we send (POST/GET)
          data: {
               EmailID: EmailID,
          },
          success: function (data) {
               // when successfully sent data and returned
               alert(data); //It returns correct value here
               return data;
          },
     });
}
```

And this is where I call the function -

```
function Confirm(button) {
     var input = document.getElementById("UserEmail");
     var checkUser = CheckUser(input.value);
     alert(checkUser); //This does not return correct value and return "undefined"
     if (input.value == "") {
          alert("Pls enter a value!");
     } else if (checkUser == "true") {
          alert("User Doesn't Exist!");
     } else {
          //Do Something...
     }
}
```

When I try alerting the data in the AJAX function it works correctly, but when I try alerting it in the second function, it returns "undefined"

### Tried Solutions

I tried using the `callback()` method instead of `return` but it still does not work and returns the same result. I used `callback()` like this -

```
callback(data);
```

So does anyone has any solution to my problem? Thanks in advance!

By the way, thinking it is not relevant, I did not add PHP code, if I need to then please tell me in the comments.

Comment: Where did you declare that callback?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I used the `callback` instead of `return`.

Comment: You have to pass the callback as an argument

Comment: @KonradLinkowski What do you mean? Can you show it as code? Because there was a SO question like this and they used `callback` as I used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CheckUser(EmailID, callback) {
     alert(EmailID);
     $.ajax("AJAXcommands\\CheckUser.php", {
          type: "POST", // type of the data we send (POST/GET)
          data: {
               EmailID: EmailID,
          },
          success: function (data) {
               // when successfully sent data and returned
               alert(data); //It returns correct value here
               callback(data)
          },
     });
}
```

```
function Confirm(button) {
     var input = document.getElementById("UserEmail");
     CheckUser(input.value, data => {
          alert(data);
          if (input.value == "") {
               alert("Pls enter a value!");
          } else if (data== "true") {
               alert("User Doesn't Exist!");
          } else {
               //Do Something...
          }
     }
}
```